# How do you say "I do" as in when you are about to get married?

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to figure out what the chinese equivalent of "I do" would be. Is there a phrase that people say in Chinese that represents getting married? Or is there a direct translation for "I do"?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this ,we have to trace back to the question asked when proposing/ getting married.

The question you should ask a girl is  : `你願意嫁給我嗎？`

Well, if you are proposing to a boy : `你願意娶我嗎？`

These two different verbs 嫁 and 娶 for "marry" are due to traditional Chinese culture.

The standard answer to a `你願意__嗎？` question would be : `是 （YES)` or `是，我願意 （YES,I do)` or simply `我願意(I do)`

Comment: FYI, it is rare for Chinese women to propose to men.

Comment: Yes Pete, but just in case :P

Answer (score 6):

`我愿意`.

It has become a fixed idiom for `I do`.

Comment: 电视剧＜＜传奇之王＞＞02 http://www.letv.com/ptv/vplay/1453571.html，has church wedding scene with 林天龙(柳云龙饰) pronouncing 我愿意 twice（时间标记 ４０：４７，４１：０９）（before being arrested）。